# Where is the bridge that was built between Sri Lanka and India in the epic Ramayana?

Tags: ramayana, history

I have a question about our epic ,Ramayana  .It was said that Lord Srirama built a bridge between India and Sri Lanka with the help of his vanara senna ,if so where is that bridge ?

Comment: You can't find evidence for god in this material world.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Description of Ram Setu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22383/description-of-ram-setu)

Comment: Here is similar question - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19257/what-happened-to-shri-ram-setu-after-returning-from-lanka

Comment: Hey @SwiftPushkar that question is marked as duplicate & original question also doesn't have any answer. I think there is no clarity for the epic bridge till now. I found this article about Discovery channel which claims to find Ram Setu. Check it out. https://www.firstpost.com/tech/news-analysis/science-channel-to-air-show-with-ground-breaking-evidence-on-ram-setu-bridge-claims-its-man-made-4255663.html

Comment: @sarvajeetsuman Yes , i am aware that  there are no answers  . So not voted to close . :-)

Comment: some helpful info here http://www.amusingplanet.com/2017/06/ramas-bridge-bridge-built-by-monkeys.html

Comment: it is at Rameswaram. The remnants of it are the sandbars that lie between the there and Sri Lanka. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rameswaram

Comment: @sarvajeetsuman I think that link has the answer to my question

Comment: @Akash.B If it helps, you are welcome & you can upvote my comment. It may help others.

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15314/what-happened-to-the-rama-setu-after-ramayana/35447#35447

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following issues are to be noted for understanding the reasons for non-existence of bridge constructed by Sri Rama, now.

1. The distance between the land from where Sri Hanuman flew towards Lanka of Ravana was 100 Yojanas,ie., [nearly 1300 Kms.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8991/3869)
2. Ravana's Lanka was not present day Sri Lanka.
3. As per the Ocean God's assurance to Sri Rama, the bridge got constructed by Sri Rama would collapse after the to and fro journey of Sri Rama and his army towards Lanka.

> विधास्ये येन गन्तासि विषहिष्ये ह्यहम् तथा | न ग्राहा विधमिष्यन्ति
> यावत्सेना तरिष्यति || २-२२-२८ हरीणाम् तरणे राम करिष्यामि यथास्थलम् |
>
> "O, Rama! **I shall make it possible to see that you are able to cross
> over. I will arrange a place for the monkeys to cross me and bear with
> it.** As far as the army crosses me, the crocodiles will not be
> aggressive to them."
>
> अयम् सौम्य नलो नाम तनुजो विश्व कर्मणः | पित्रा दत्त वरः श्रीमान्
> प्रतिमो विश्व कर्मणः || २-२२-४४
>
> "O, excellent man! This one, named Nala, a glorious person, is the son
> of Vishvakarma; who was given a boon by his father and is equal to
> Visvakarma."
>
> एष सेतुम् महाउत्साहः करोतु मयि वानरः | तम् अहम् धारयिष्यामि तथा हि एष
> यथा पिता || २-२२-४५
>
> "Let this greatly energetic monkey build a bridge across me. I can
> hold that bridge. He is just the same as his father."

So the bridge got constructed by Sri Rama would be in place, as long as He and his army pass over it, ie., it will remain intact for their to and fro journeys. There after it will collapse.

Sri Rama performed the return journey by Pushpaka Vimana and hence the bridge would have been collapsed immediately thereafter.