# Goddess Pārvatī brother, Maināka parvata?

Tags: scripture, parvati, reference-request

I have [read](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=RqG1AAAAIAAJ&q=%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%95%20%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A4%20%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%80&dq=%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%95%20%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A4%20%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%80&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_1dru7qfvAhX1IbcAHZ9WAjEQ6AEwAXoECAEQAw) and watched at several places and TV soaps, about [Maināka](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/mainaka) parvata as the son of [Himavant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himavat) and Maināvatī, and thus, being the brother of [Devī Pārvatī](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Mainak?wprov=sfla1) and brother-in-law to Lord Shiva?

What are the scriptural references for him and what are his various stories - both as a personified human brother to the Goddess and as a Mountain (in reference to being saved by Vayu deva from Indra) ?

Also, the references to flying mountains and them having wings, are found in the Puranic or Vedic literature. And then Indra cut off the mountains' wings using his *vajra*.

Where exactly in the present day context will be the *lavana samundra*, where the *Maināka parvata* Submerged itself? Did others mountains submerge themselves too? If yes, which all and where (especially, with reference to present geography)?

Comment: Oh oh mainaka, I’ve read some Purana or V Ramayana. Can’t place where. And the mountains wing thing there’s already a question on the site: [Did mountains used to have wings](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/1962/did-mountains-use-to-have-wings). The purana says mean was the daughter of Pitrs and from her was born Mainaka.

Comment: You meant mean = mainavati?, @Archit

Comment: Ya mena = menavati

Comment: Thanks for reference to the flying mountain answer @Archit