# What to make of this Shloka in Valmiki Ramayana where it talks of flying mountains?

Tags: scripture, ramayana, history, science, valmiki

Valmiki Ramayana Sundara Kanda Shloka 1.123 ( Complete - 5.1.123 Valmiki Ramayana) talks of flying mountains in KritaYuga.

पूर्वं कृतयुगे तात पर्वताः पक्षिणोऽभवन्।

ते हि जग्मुर्दिशः सर्वा गरुडानिलवेगिनः।।5.1.123।।

"Formerly in Kritayuga, O dear, mountains were endowed with wings. They used to move speedily in all directions like Garuda and the Windgod." (Translation)

Now what to make of this verse? Because this clearly says that mountains used to have wings in the KritaYuga and it is said in the next verses that those wings were later cut off. How to make sense of this in the context of what we know about the history of mountains? Is the mainstream perception about the history of all mountains wrong or what to make of this verse?

Comment: Mountains here are a particular race of beings. They have the same name/similar name as inanimate mountains, because they are mountains to other beings, because of their size and shape. It's like how coral refers to both the tiny animals and the structures they make.

Comment: Are you saying that Parvata refers to a race of beings and not mountains? Not sure if you've properly read the entire thing also. It's written in the next verses that the wings of the mountains were later cut off except of the one Mainaka Mountain, so to me, it looks like it's talking about mountains itself and not something else and hence, I'm not sure how to make sense of that.

Comment: The race are literally mountains. As in you can walk on them, rivers flow down them, etc. Mainaka and the other "mountains" are clearly sentient beings from their other appearances and also big enough to function just like inanimate mountains.

Comment: So what happened to that race? Are they the same as the mountains that we see in the world today?

Comment: I had closed the question but I have removed my close vote. Let others decide too. @light_10

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/1962

Comment: Yeah thanks @Rickross I have read that question and it does not answer this one. I have also written about how the 2 questions are different in the edit to this post.

Comment: @light_10 Ok no problem, Let other users decide.

Comment: @light_10 Unlikely that they are. Some are away from Earth anyway, so you can't see them.

Comment: Which ones are you talking about that are away from earth? Where is in the shaastra are those written about?

Comment: Use @[name of the person you are replying to] if you want to reply. I think I remember the Harivaṃśa talking about a mountain that refused to lie or betray in a situation that would be very weird if it was on Earth.